# Replace IP using AWK or SED

Tags: awk, sed

I have to replace an IP in a script so I used a variable to store the output of awk like for instance:

```
existing_ip=$(awk --field-separator '=' '/10.171.0.231/ { print $2; }' file.txt)
```

On the other hand I am also taking user input like:

```
read -p  "What is the IP address to be replace: " new_ip

echo -e "New IP: ${new_ip}"
```

Now in the next step I am facing an issue when I try to replace the IP with sed or awk command. I have tried using the below commands but none worked.

```
awk -v s="$existing_ip"  '{gsub(/10.171.[0-9].{1,3}.[0-9]/, s)}1'

sed -i "s/${existing_ip}/${new_ip}/g"
```

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to specify an input file for the awk and sed commands. E.g., `sed -i "s/${existing_ip}/${new_ip}/g" file.txt`. The sed command substitutes the given pattern within the input file.

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your efforts, could you please also share few lines of samples of input and expected output in your question to make it more clear, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from mentioned in the comment that you have to specify an input file, the pattern `10.171.[0-9].{1,3}.[0-9]` can match for example `10a171b0cdef2` as you have to escape the dot to match it literally.

If you escape the dot, the quantifier `{1,3}` would go after matching a digit at the end. So you would match a single digit in the 3rd part, and 1-3 digits in the 4th part.

```
cat file.txt

This is ip 10.171.1.111 and this is ip 10.172.0.231
```

For example

```
existing_ip="10.171.0.231"
awk -v s="$existing_ip"  '{gsub(/10\.171\.[0-9]\.[0-9]{1,3}/, s)}1' file.txt
```

Output

```
This is ip 10.171.0.231 and this is ip 10.172.0.231
```